# Having trouble getting datepicker style to appear in my Rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, styles

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have included these gems

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I would like to use a date picker on my page, which I have done in my coffee script like so …

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> $('#datepicker').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    altField: '#user_object_day'
    onSelect: (date) ->
      update();
```

but I’m having trouble getting the datepicker style to show up on my page.  I have this in my ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme'
@import "jquery.ui.core"
@import "jquery.ui.theme"
@import "jquery.ui.datepicker"
```

However the styling for the date picker doesn’t appear.  Here’s what is produced in my HTML …

```
    <head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-f7b997caf712f3060ad616e13504564b0a9628b98eaf796c98a22c85e4807b99.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/user_exercises.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-806fd2c66749900d7cd54ad2f2f8b72f2057fe85c9ec5b553242f0f13bec856e.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-93be4d22eda916787802a64d8f88b52db8a9027d4ccbbc0942625324a7d12d44.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-c1602241ddc51216b58391768667068867b8e15b9efc722befcd25771eda6819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-c95f320275150a94241b004a91e21eef9c5ae9965a793cb3e2475f6078a1670d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-e693ced4ecfa1a276f0b794f32c1d30d792764b08788bf68ecfa3b388c291333.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/menu.self-7abc1c9401509a7e4fc609b1e461be6fd17e8116e8fda19cc59d05ba79aefb68.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-3befc48aba87cead090cfd014562b2771a662ac6d2c8197b24c08b2d9f3d9f2d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/button.self-4d4f21ba77bbf8cc08ae65e2b6329a7a1b952b32c3ba7bffca8313e7e8c93d0c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-6267be6d4d0f0e8665be3b4d6ac07f40ba23a32aff8eaa5d1bfc00f76a9eeae7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.self-c513294e8da73f31f84ba3ef11e2a1180a47faea0eb2fea4a53fc26153dd21fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.self-debcca3d0d5d9afe2fe91a6fd1aebdb41ca0a55f2f6017352e6c02b6d8a6e64c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.self-60b870565f3cd62982c1907828119bb51f42ec8228d5e23868153edc3abc685c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.self-5a6c7980dfa3f6b74445b0f4b20eed799ee65363163500ed7f032e603d6b022d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/droppable.self-a7a2b4c2cec8fc176f51e4e4291d92bfd3eec40b6a580b47fc54c16334d52882.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.self-3acdb29e7da09c8f0195b994d2f04d73bfef50dc539c84fd2c835d964d33e5c1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.self-ed102209d7aa0b7374f3db8478cc7dcff5f9980d3146e8bf9fbfab959c6d5d8a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-bounce.self-bfcb9288797ecd234ddeedf4fbc5b4c9de94a4e6d8d44e6faa5b5e9836fad9fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-clip.self-7368e4597c32360b162d264ff8bbd0cf9fb1535eb9b4564e6eb7c1db3c774bf3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-drop.self-294aaa72126ad9c94d6558cca792eb3716754713aca98f18a9dd7c493150ed92.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-explode.self-68e74dc114a52f3f4d7033e40c39196961bdcf439652daa2e98baa115c7bb44b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fade.self-42d542a5253e0a610717460102ee6bee339c656cc188e491d89eb0779043c963.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fold.self-ad9967f153423916300dbf1104b00f7ad7bbd6a222a0fcc1012ebe251bcb13c8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-highlight.self-f922b7179ab8ccfa7865141f38865bba0a3d2bdceba7561c27ca14544dbfd996.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-size.self-368aecefa09656a2be5c72dc8e685b120363a3df812134cbd2dd998bafa179fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-scale.self-884a5abcb6d90fcd9f9a071aa8329638184df688afced1b1d3b6be6c69f4dd7f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-puff.self-93415831093923a70f671d73e8d0b3d94deb37ac7472a036a4add545f565c166.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.self-eb107c0d136eccdfbd8a2f0f2ee71e0f6911cb300c6b63cc2fe4f6532e6a9a97.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-shake.self-63bcc14897aac5b84e10690be94d64d5724f864aa14c913b4d1030c461a256ad.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-slide.self-c93054a4a80d1f986760806d81ab067e4a4120bf103337e152ecc24d36e785f6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-transfer.self-181245634ec522320fc1081f6dbf94fd982f34eefa03555f76817dedfcdea336.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.self-a259ff5a2a5e7aef0ec21bda94edd0f6bc1e9821128d901de415956edf212b0d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.self-42e53fc2f95211314e36a8094c42560f869c207f16d68cfc206aa37201dcdc03.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.self-09dbcac573f0e508194bd9deff254db090889b380d030261857860309c0918e8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/slider.self-8af8d2a0661743ba88b4cfb99d5c8c874cfa3fc6528ae4e9252366b388def0b7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.self-df2d80a36f9dfbe0facc596ccd92af83ca50d38e4cd6a84810aaf5d40b8cd181.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.self-3c8c95a7bc9c877d0f9c16789246bbedda6b8e8fbf5927951babdab775aed02e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.self-dc07b44bf1b926c8d28ccd2658e30933881e5329348caf70cf305c3943f6bbd7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.self-38f04ac3a6c8fb2391ec6832b68845671cc9013a94371b7eb239478f4835eb73.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></scipt>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.self-52111578aa54225c9ebfe06f78a62771020ee548bb27d62228ee3f5e6633969d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d602bdfe68ffc63b9f9cc512872aa3cfff046228a0a36e90dd476e8ef54c1b09.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/user_exercises.self-ebd6c787c7885684d8edc3ce54d013ea6715290fa04091d45a109b1965d4fc4b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.self-f8806224e027f3e3f0138ea9ce99319e298dfdb323304d1f1be6eae8e8c74724.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="rensyCNrdgwj8yyZinV+5JrceZ06gG7wj8tIsaV/5YonD5c+CIbp+wHxL6s+gtnOaMPjA3j8zwUeJ+8S6jXjAA==" />
    </head>
```

How do I edit my application.css file to get the datepicker style to appear?

Comment: Are you using CSS or SASS for your application.css? `//= require jquery-ui` will require datepicker.

Comment: I don't know -- I just built my project and I didn't program anything involving SASS.  The file application.css was basically auto-geneated for me (I have included the complete file in my question).  How do I figure out if it is CSS or SASS?

Comment: Well, the `@import` tell's me is sass, the extension should be `.scss` (let's start there), But you said `application.css`. If you follow jquery-rails install see, they don't use @imports, but `//= requires`. First things first, let's fix jquery-ui first, and then worry about bootstrap, don't try to chew too much on a single bite. Please update your question

Comment: Ok, so to fix jquery-ui, I need to rename ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css to ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ?  I swear, I added the lines "@import "jquery.ui.core"," "@import "jquery.ui.theme"," and "@import "jquery.ui.datepicker" but everytnign else was there from before.

Comment: Well, it's your code, so you can remove it too. It will help to reduce the noise around the problem you are having. Please follow the instructions on how to setup jquery-ui-rails: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails: it's not using `@import`

Comment: I added "*= require jquery-ui" in the appropriate spot and removed the @import jquery lines and now the styles show up properly.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer to reflect what we discuss in the comments. If it worked for you, please marked your question as answered, so others can find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions on how to setup *query-ui-rails* from their [README](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails):

Instead of using `@import` statements, use sprockets:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

That should require all the necessary files for you, including *jquery-ui/datepicker.css*